# Assemblies collection not showing shared assemblies in AssemblyLoadContext

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, .net-core-3.1

I have a question about AssemblyLoadContext (noted ALC from now) and shared assemblies.

- In my design, I have a shared assembly, which is loaded in a custom ALC, noted S.
- This assembly is used to allow communication between two other assemblies loaded in their own ALC (two separate assemblies in two separate ALCs), noted A and B.
- When I take a look at the Assemblies property of the ALCs, I do not see the shared assembly in the A and B ALCs.
- If I load the shared assembly once more in a other ALC, noted S2, it doesn't work with ALCs A and B, as specified in the doc.

**My question is :**

- How do I see that the assembly instance used to share a contract between A and B is the assembly S and not S2?

I do not imply there is a bug, it works as the documentation says (as far as I understand it), I just want to "***see***" that ALCs A and B "use" assembly from ALC S, and therefore cannot work with S2.